# How to split up (messy main, large repo) git branch into multiple branches?

Tags: git, split, branch

Throughout my development I've committed everything to the main branch. The result is that I have a really messy main branch. I want to split my `main` into a `branch1` and `branch2` branch. For example, I have something like this:

```
Main --- A --- C --- B --- E --- D
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
   Branch1  B --- E
          /
Main --- A
          \
   Branch2  C --- D
```

Based on my understanding (which may be wrong), if there are no conflicts, this should be possible. Is there a way to do this? If there are conflicts, how would I handle it?

It should be noted that my repo is quite big (`.git` folder is ~35 GB). I'm in the process of moving large files to Git LFS, but believe have to do implement this in each individual commit (whigh could take a long time). I think all commands I'm using are now serverly slowed down because of this, causing a painfully long wait time.

Comment: Note that if you split up large file sizes between branches, then switching branches could be a slow(er) operation, compared to your current state.

Comment: @TTT Thank you for the heads up - will keep note of it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git rebase --onto` _twice` here:

```
# from Main
git rebase --onto A C
git rebase --onto C E
```

The first command says to move on top of commit `A` the commit whose parent is `C`, which is the `B` commit.  The first rebase leaves the diagram looking like this:

```
Branch1:  B -- E -- D
         /
Main:   A
         \
Branch2:  C
```

The second rebase moves the `D` commit on top of `C`, which should leave us with your expected result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. I updated my question with more relevant information about the `.git` folder size. Would this change your answer?

Comment: @Wilan Large files in your Git repo is another issue, perhaps not related to or affected by this.  Most of the "work" for Git in my answer is just moving around branch pointers; the content remains the same.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Will try your solution and see if it works.